# Using reserved JPQL keywords with JPA

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I have an entity class called "Group" and NetBeans warns me "The entity table name is a reserved Java Persistence QL keyword".

A similar case would be the use of reserved SQL keywords.

Will this name be escaped? Would the use of a different table name solve the problem @Table(name="otherName"). Or should I rename the class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Will this name be escaped?

There is **nothing** in the JPA spec that says so, if your provider does, this is provider specific.

> Would the use of a different table name solve the problem @Table(name="otherName")

Obviously, it would (as long as you don't use another reserved keyword of course). But if you are using a JPA 2.0 provider, there is a standard way to get a db object name escaped, with double quotes:

```
@Table(name="\"Group\"")
```

In JPA 1.0, there is nothing standard, it depends on your JPA provider. For example, Hibernate uses backticks:

```
@Table(name="`Group`")
```

> Or should I rename the class?

No. The table name of an entity defaults to the entity name but you can control it using the `@Table` annotation as we saw. There is thus no need to change the class name of your entity.

Comment: If you use quotes like that, any combination table (f.e. OneToMany relations) will fail to be created ("Group"_Members f.e. is an invalid name). This solution is a hack, and I would recommend not using reserved names for Tables. Field names pose less of an issue.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to rename the class - and you shouldn't - the name you have chosen reflects your domain in the best way, and you should not change it because of tool or framework limitations, in case the tool/framework provides a way to avoid the "clash". JPA provides such a way.

Comment: No, the name element of `@Entity(name"foo")` is something else, it is used to defined the name to be used in JPQL queries. It has noting to do with database objects.