# JPQL MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, exception, orm, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have two entities User and Group:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="user_group", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USERNAME")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID")})
    private List<Group> group;

    // getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class Group implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

It's ManyToMany unidirectional. It produces tables `user` and `user_group`. Now I have simple query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select g from Group g");
List<Group> usersGroup = q.getResultList();
```

which throws exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: SELECT ID FROM GROUP
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Group sql="SELECT ID FROM GROUP")
... stack trace...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call your user group entity 'Group'. It's be a reserved word in MySQL syntax for use in aggregation as [GROUP BY](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php).

Try calling it something else, like 'UserGroup'.

Comment: When I call it `Group` it creates `user` and `user_group` but it doesn't create `group` table and it doesn't throw any exception while creating these tables. Is the name really the reason? When I change it to `Groupp` it does create three tables though: `user`, `user_group`, `groupp`.

Comment: Correction it does throw error for entity `Group` but not for `User`. Why is that? `User` is also reserved keyword (that's what NetBeans is saying at least)

Comment: Are you invoking a similar select call for user when you try to replicate the problem? Regardless, as a general rule just avoid  database table names that could clash with reserved words/function names in your database - easily eliminates one source of errors that may vary from database type to database type.

Comment: Found this question, similar and has the same advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153881/using-reserved-jpql-keywords-with-jpa

Answer (score 5):

You CAN use `Group` or `User` for the database objects as long as you tell the JPA provider that these names have to be interpreted as delimited identifiers.

With JPA 2.0 and annotations, a name is specified as a delimited identifier by enclosing the name within double quotes, whereby the inner quotes are escaped:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"User\"")
public class User implements Serializable {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="\"Group\"")
public class Group implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

#### Reference

- JPA 2.0 specification

  - Section 2.13 "Naming of Database Objects"