# JPQL query with reserved keyword "set"

Tags: jpa, jpql

The following query produces an error:

```
select e from CrmSetText e where e.set.id = 1
```

I assume the problem is with the field named "set" on the entity CrmSetText. Is it possible to escape this keyword or would I need to rename the field on this entity?

I've found a question about Table names on this site ([Using reserved JPQL keywords with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153881/using-reserved-jpql-keywords-with-jpa)) but not about fields.

Below is the error I get from executing the query:

```
JpqlSyntaxException: Errors found for input jpql:[select e from CrmSetText e where e.set.id = 1] CommonErrorNode [<unexpected: [@30,61:61='.',<68>,1:61], resync=e.set.id = 1>]
```

Comment: "SET" is a reserved keyword, yes. But in an UPDATE statement. I would expect an error only when you have "SET" surrounded by spaces, which is not your case. You don't say which JPA provider is throwing that exception.

Comment: @DN1
The framework is using EclipseLink.

Comment: Raise a bug on your JPA provider. You cannot "escape" field names, only table/column names. And if your JPA provider won't fix it in real time, then you'd have to either use a different JPA provider, or rename the field

Comment: The same error occur if you use: `select e from CrmSetText e JOIN e.set s where s.id = 1`?